# List[Try[T]] to Try[List[T]] in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I would like to know how to convert a `List[Try[T]]` into `Try[List[T]]` in Scala?

I have tried using an accumulator and folding right but it doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: `Try(list.map(_.get))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using cats it's as easy as:

```
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val tries: List[Try[Int]] = List(Success(1), Success(2), Success(3))
tries.sequence
```

More information in the [Traverse docs](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html).

Answer (score 7):

```
Try(list.map(_.get))
```

This will return only the first failure, so you need something more complicated if you want to catch all the failures in the list.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074846/how-to-transform-a-seqtry-to-a-tryseq) for the code that catches multiple failures.

Answer (score 4):

I would also recommend just using **Cats**...

But, if you do not want to add another *(big)* dependency to your project, just for one function.
You can implement it your self! - *(cats implementation may be better)*

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def sequence[A](list: List[Try[A]]): Try[List[A]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[Try[A]], acc: List[A]): Try[List[A]] =
    remaining match {
      case Nil                => Success(acc.reverse)
      case Success(a) :: tail => loop(remaining = tail, acc = a :: acc)
      case Failure(e) :: _    => Failure(e)
    }
  loop(remaining = list, acc = List.empty)
}
```

Also, if you may use `traverse` instead of `sequence` if you did a `map` just before.

```
def traverse[A, B](list: List[A])(f: A => Try[B]): Try[List[B]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[A], acc: List[B]): Try[List[B]] =
    remaining match {
      case Nil          => Success(acc.reverse)
      case head :: tail => f(head) match {
        case Success(b) => loop(remaining = tail, acc = b :: acc)
        case Failure(e) => Failure(e)
      }
    }
  loop(remaining = list, acc = List.empty)
}
```

---

Anyways, **Cats** *(and FP in general)* is very useful *(as you have just seen)*.
Thus, I would recommend you to give it a try.

Comment: Nice solution.  I suppose method `traverse` should take a `List[Try[A]]` rather than `List[A]`, consequently `f(head) match {...}` should be something like `head.flatMap(f) match {...}`.

Comment: @LeoC No, [**traverse**](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Traverse.html#traverse[G[_],A,B](fa:F[A])(f:A=%3EG[B])(implicitevidence$1:cats.Applicative[G]):G[F[B]]) is defined as `traverse[G[_] : Applicative, A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => G[B]): G[F[B]]` - Thus, in this specific case, the idea is to have a list of plain values and and a function that will transform these into **Try**-effectual values. Remember that `col.map(f).sequence === col.traverse(f)`, that is why I said that you can use it if you did a **map** just before.

Answer (score 2):

Cats is a nice way to go but it can be done via the Standard Library without too much complication.

```scala
import util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def seqnc[T](lst :List[Try[T]]) :Try[List[T]] =
  lst.foldRight(Try(List.empty[T])) {
    case (tt, acc) => for { t <- tt
                            a <- acc
                          } yield t :: a
  }
```