# Scala Comparison of 2 different Object Sequences

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am coming from Java background and learning Scala now. I have a `Seq` respectively for `Loc` and `LocSize` objects whereby these 2 objects share a common member field `code`. I have a `validateRoom` function that basically validates these two `Seq` by matching a `Loc` instance to a `LocSize` instance and make some basic validation operations. My objective is to make sure all Loc objects passes the validation, hence I am using `Seq.forall` at the last `println`.

I believe that there are better, shorter and prettier FP ways to achieve what I want. How can I do so?

```
case class Loc(id: String, code: String, isRoom: Boolean, measureUnit: String, allowedSize: Int)

case class LocSize(code: String, width: Int, length: Int, measureUnit: String)

val locs = Seq(
  Loc("_1", "loc01", true, "M", 100),
  Loc("_2", "loc02", false, "M", 100),
  Loc("_3", "loc03", true, "M", 100)
)

val locSizes = Seq(
  LocSize("loc01", 5, 10, "M"),
  LocSize("loc02", 6, 11, "M"),
  LocSize("loc03", 9, 14, "M"),
  LocSize("loc04", 8, 13, "M"),
  LocSize("loc05", 9, 14, "M"),
)

def validateRoom(locs: Seq[Loc], loSizes: Seq[LocSize]): Seq[Boolean] = {
  for (loc <- locs) yield {
    if (loc.isRoom) {
      val locSize = loSizes.find(_.code == loc.code)

      locSize match {
        case Some(i) => {
          if (i.measureUnit.contains(loc.measureUnit) &&
           i.width*i.length < loc.allowedSize)
            true
          else
            false
        }
        case None => false
      }
    }
    else
      true
  }
}

// Return false as loc03 size 9*14 > 100
println(validateRoom(locs, locSizes).forall(b => b))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option you have is:

```scala
def validateRoom(locs: Seq[Loc], locSizes: Seq[LocSize]): Boolean = {
  locs.forall(loc => !loc.isRoom || locSizes.find(_.code == loc.code).exists(locSize => {
    locSize.measureUnit.contains(loc.measureUnit) &&
      locSize.width*locSize.length < loc.allowedSize
  }))
}
```

Why does it work?

[`forall`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/IterableOnce.scala#L574) makes sure for any `loc` in `locs`, the condition should be true.

What is the codition?

First, `loc.isRoom` should br true, then `locSizes` should find `LocSize` with the same `code`. The result of [`find`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/IterableOnce.scala#L618) is an [`Option`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L144), which exposes the method [`exists`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L405). `exists` makes sure the option is not empty, and the boolean inside is true.

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/5BsWokVmQWeaNHLZmXdPDw/2).

Answer (score 2):

YMMV and there are probably other more elegant solutions, here is one example

```scala
def validateRooms(locs: Seq[Loc], loSizes: Seq[LocSize]): Boolean = {
  locs.foldLeft(true){ (state, loc) =>
    if (state) {
      val locSize = loSizes.find(_.code == loc.code)
      locSize.map( s =>
                 s.measureUnit.contains(loc.measureUnit) &&
           s.width*s.length < loc.allowedSize).getOrElse(false)
    } else {
      state
    }
  }
}
```

In this case the function returns the result `true` if all are valid eliminating the `forall`. Uses `map` and `foldleft` to eliminate the for comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

A better functional approach is to not really in **Booleans** at all, but rather provide more meaningful types; for example, an `Either`.
If you are open to using [**cats**](https://typelevel.org/cats/), the code is as simple as:

```scala
import cats.syntax.all._

// In general, a validation should return a new type, maybe a LocWithSize or something.
// The idea of a new type is to proof the type system that such value is already validated.
def validateRoom(locs: List[Loc], loSizes: List[LocSize]): Either[String, List[Loc]] ={
  val sizesByCode = locSizes.iterator.map(ls => ls.code -> ls).toMap
  
  locs.traverse { loc =>
    sizesByCode
      .get(key = loc.code)
      .toRight(left = s"The code: '${loc.code}' was not found in the sizes")
      .flatMap { locSize =>
        val size = locSize.width * locSize.length
        
        if (locSize.measureUnit != loc.measureUnit)
          Left(s"The mesaure unit: '${locSize.measureUnit}' was not applicable to the location: ${loc}")
        else if (size > loc.allowedSize)
          Left(s"The size of location '${loc.code}' was ${size} which is bigger than the allowed size (${loc.allowedSize})")
        else
          Right(loc)
      }
  }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```scala
val locs = List(
  Loc("_1", "loc01", true, "M", 100),
  Loc("_2", "loc02", false, "M", 100),
  Loc("_3", "loc03", true, "M", 100)
)

val locSizes = List(
  LocSize("loc01", 5, 10, "M"),
  LocSize("loc02", 6, 11, "M"),
  LocSize("loc03", 9, 14, "M"),
  LocSize("loc04", 8, 13, "M"),
  LocSize("loc05", 9, 14, "M")
)

validateRoom(locs, locSizes)
// res: Either[String, List[Loc]] = Left(The size of location 'loc03' was 126 which is bigger than the allowed size (100))
```

If you do not want to pull out **cats** just for this, you can implement your own `traverse`.
Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57517258/4111404) for an example using `Try`, the logic should be pretty similar.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/8J5BL2yxQsS6vQrmKz8ycw/2)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can go cleaner like:

```
def validateRoom(locs: Seq[Loc], loSizes: Seq[LocSize]): Boolean = {
    val locSizeIndex: Map[String, LocSize] = loSizes.map(loc => loc.code -> loc).toMap
    val validation = for {
      room <- locs.filter(_.isRoom)
      size <- locSizeIndex.get(room.code)
    } yield size.measureUnit.contains(room.measureUnit) && size.width * size.length < room.allowedSize
    validation.reduceOption(_ && _).getOrElse(true)
}

// Return false as loc03 size 9*14 > 100
println(validateRoom(locs, locSizes))
```

Which prints out `false`

Scatie for playing: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xQbDWZXOR16PJhz6xeaByA